# Change type of QGIS message bar with widget

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I followed the following tutorial to create a QGIS message bar with widget, but it is being shown as a warning message (orange color). https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/communicating.html#showing-messages-the-qgsmessagebar-class

[image]

But I want to show the message bar as info (blue color) not as warning (orange color). I know there is level parameter in `iface.messageBar().pushMessage()` which I can set to `Qgis.Info` but there is no such parameter in `iface.messageBar().createMessage()` which is used for widget. https://qgis.github.io/pyqgis/3.0/gui/Message/QgsMessageBar.html#qgis.gui.QgsMessageBar.createMessage

**How can I change the type of message bar with widget.**

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that all that is needed is to drop `Qgis.Warning` in the last line. It will then default to `Qgis.Info`

```py
def showError():
    pass

widget = iface.messageBar().createMessage("Missing Layers", "Show Me")
button = QPushButton(widget)
button.setText("Show Me")
button.pressed.connect(showError)
widget.layout().addWidget(button)
# iface.messageBar().pushWidget(widget, Qgis.Warning)
iface.messageBar().pushWidget(widget)
```